# Как сделать один медиа плейер на все Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediaplayer

Есть **Activity1** и **Activity2**.

Надо чтобы на двух Activity была одинаковая фоновая музыка, а при переходе не останавливалась, а продолжала на том чем остановилась. Подскажите реализацию и можно ли это реализовать?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш плеер не должен быть привязан к жизни `Activity`. Для этого вам необходимо реализовать `Playback Service`. 
[Service.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru)